# Get multiple objects from stage by class name in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, kineticjs

I am using using JavaScript library `Kinetic.js` for HTML5 canvas.
Here is the method `stage.get()` to get objects from stage (canvas). I have assigned the id's or class names to each object

if I get the object by id `var obj = stage.get('#obj_id')` it works but If try to get the multiple objects by class name `var objs = stage.get('.obj_class_name')` it returns an empty  `[]` object

How I can get multiple objects from stage .

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more context? Some code of how you construct the objects and where you add them to the stage would be nice. Right now, it is difficult to understand where the problem lies, since `stage.get('.object_name')` should work, as specified here: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-select-shapes-by-name-with-kineticjs/

Comment: Yep, what @Rikonator said - `stage.get('.object_name')` should work if you've defined the `name` parameter for each object. If you could provide a bit more context and/or a jsfiddle of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you could just do .getChildren() to get all children, then iterate through the array with a loop and a condition to add a new array you created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `name` attribute. It works as the `class`in HTML. Use the stage/layer function `find('.<name>')` to select all your elements with the the name `<name>` (The dot is necessary).